# Maintain a cmake project (from Eclipse CDT4)

Tags: ide, import, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I'm having some difficulties with cmake (2.8.7) and Eclipse + CDT (3.7.1). I'm using a CMakeBuilder (http://www.cmakebuilder.com/), which I found via the search function here. Actually I thought, that'd be it.

- Problem is that it does **not** provide any import function either: So I need cmake to generate Eclipse CDT4 Makefiles initially, which requires me to maintain two separate build systems and to work on copies. One for deployment, one for development.
- Furthermore I'd need to copy my changes over into the original project, file by file, because I can just work on copies, that cmake generates together with the Makefiles. At the end: twice the work. Double-check integration each time.

Is there anything one can do to work directly on a cmake project from Eclipse (or another sane IDE)? Mainly I need good C++ editing (very large set of libs, so the paths are a major problem, and cmake searches for these on every platform). I could maintain cmake on my own, but Eclipse (and other IDEs) miss a useful import settings. Some IDE would be nice though. ;)

Best,
Marius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I remember [KDevelop4](http://kdevelop.org/) has native support. In other hand: why don't edit `CMakeLists.txt` directly as a simple script (from an editor*) and use the [official GUI](http://cmake.org/)? I haven't used Eclipse with CMake, but in Visual Studio the solution is generated automatically after editing any of project or solution `CMakeLists.txt` file. I expect something similar from Eclipse, too.

[Eclipse CDT4 Generator](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/Eclipse_CDT4_Generator)

[More info.](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Editors_Support)

*: [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) has highlight for CMake files.

Comment: problem is not that I cannot edit cmakes files with any editor, but that the projects have tons of libs and I'd need to manually locate each lib to check for sane use of any API.